# How to Return a value into a method?

Tags: c#

I am not sure i am using the right choice of words. I have this variable fibo2 and inside there is another variable nearclose. nearclose is coming from the result of a process of formulas. At the end of the script nearclose return a number, lets say 10. It returns 10 because fibo2 starts by calculating at the beginning with the variable Close.GetValueAt(CurrentBar):

```
fibo2 = (Close.GetValueAt(CurrentBar) - lowPrice0) / (Ncma - lowPrice0);
```

Once the first calculation is done i want to replace Close.GetValueAt(CurrentBar) by the result of nearclose, 10. I can do it manually like this by replacing Close.GetValueAt(CurrentBar) by 10:

```
fibo2 = (10 - lowPrice0) / (Ncma - lowPrice0);
```

and nearclose at the end returns a new value 11. So that the next time 11 replace 10 to produce a new value that will again replace 11. This way i can create a list of all values after processing every bars.

So i decided to replace Close.GetValueAt(CurrentBar) by nearclose:

```
fibo2 = (nearclose - lowPrice0) / (Ncma - lowPrice0);
```

The problem its creating somekind of internal loop and return 0 or the wrong value.

Edited Part:

Now this is a small example of the main idea:

```
    double fibo2 = 0;
    double nearclose = 8;
    double lowPrice0 = 4;
    double Ncma = 5;
    double x = 10;  
        
        
        
        
        fibo2 = (nearclose - lowPrice0) / (Ncma - lowPrice0);
        
        
        nearclose = fibo2 * x;
        
        
            var numbers = new List<double> {};
            numbers.Add(nearclose);
            
            
        foreach (var item in numbers)
            {   
                
                Print(item);
            
            }
```

The Print return 40 but if you replace nearclose by 40 it will returned 360.Than in the list you end up with {8, 40, 360 ...}
You send back the new value produced by nearclose to nearclose itself in fibo2.
In my code (not this sample) nearclose = 0; because the result come from formulas generated by a for loop of bars in a chart. I hope this help more.

Edited part 2020-10-27

```
public void WhateverTheChartingNameIs()
                {
                    
                    var barCount = 3;    
                    var results = new List<double> { nearclose };
                    
                    for(int i = 0; i < barCount; i++)
                    {
                        var result = RunCalculation(results[i]); 
                        results.Add(result);

                        Print("Result"+result);
                    }
                }
                        

                        
    private double RunCalculation(double nearclose)
            {
                
                return (nearclose - lowPrice0) / (Ncma - lowPrice0);
            }
```

Comment: it is quite hard to understand the question, honestly; nothing in anything shown is about "returning" anything, and the code shown isn't runnable, so we can't see what you're seeing (nor would it be clear what you're *expecting* to see). A lot of things shown in the code that *is* there aren't actually *declared*, and we can't see if they are locals, fields, etc; nor can we see if you're trying to span values between multiple methods. Many things are *possible*, but there isn't much here to understand what you're trying to do, to offer guidance. Could you perhaps make it runnable?

Comment: FWIW, I expect "add `ref` to the offending parameter" is a likely fix here, but very hard to say without context

Comment: How long should this run for? In your example you've fixed this in the while loop to be 3 times, but where does that 3 come from?

Comment: "Its a 700 lines code." - the trick, when asking questions like this, is not to post *more* - it is to post *less*; what is the minimum code that shows the same *problem*, but perhaps with a lot less specifics? I'd be amazed if the same problem can't be shown in 10-20 lines of fully runnable code, for example:  (completely unrelated code): https://gist.github.com/mgravell/c4f9590f72f9be4687bb188df2e01d2d (essentially: anything that we *can possibly* remove because it isn't needed to show the actual problem: **usually isn't relevant to the question**, and as such we *should* remove it)

Comment: I am reading about ref in docs.micro to learn about it. I will try to create a sample. I am not sure what offending parameter is. thanks

Comment: the number of times depend the number of bars in the chart. for now, 3 is just an example.

Comment: "I can do it manually like this by replacing Close.GetValueAt(CurrentBar) by 10: `fibo2 = (10 - lowPrice0) / (Ncma - lowPrice0);` and nearclose at the end returns a new value 11"  How?!  `nearclose` is not in that calculation, so it wouldn't be changed.  No one can answer this question because you haven't accurately represented what is happening.  Post more complete code that shows us how all these values interact with each other.  Is `nearclose` being changed by nearby code in some kind of loop?  Is it being changed by a SIDE EFFECT of calling `Close.GetValueAt()`?  Who knows?...

Comment: i am working on it, give me the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *sounds* like you simply want to run a calculation, record the result and then use that result as a variable in the next calculation for a given amount of executions. If so, I think you can do this:

```
public IList<double> CalculateResults(double startNumber, int barCount)
{    
    var results = new List<double> { startNumber };
    
    for(int i = 0; i < barCount; i++)
    {
        var result = RunCalculation(results[i]);
        results.Add(result);
    }
    
    return results;
}

private double RunCalculation(double nearClose)
{
    var lowPrice0 = //whatever this is;
    var Ncma = //whatever this is;
    return (nearClose - lowPrice0) / (Ncma - lowPrice0);
}
```

**Update**

If by your comment you mean the charting software just prints the results then rather than returning the list of results make it void and print the results instead like this:

```
public void WhateverTheChartingNameIs()
{
    var nearClose = 8;
    var barCount = 3;    
    var results = new List<double> { nearClose };
    
    for(int i = 0; i < barCount; i++)
    {
        var result = RunCalculation(results[i]); //same as above. If you can't do this just stick the logic from this method inside the for loop.
        results.Add(result);

        Print(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You understand the fundamentals. I have to produce a sample otherwise its pointless. In fact only that part is needed: fibo2 = (nearclose - lowPrice0) / (Ncma - lowPrice0);

Comment: i use a charting software that has its own class. Its not allowing public and private. By what can i replace public IList<double> CalculateResults(double startNumber, int barCount) and private double?

Comment: @Frankdot So what is the charting software's class doing? Is it returning the results or just printing them?

Comment: First have you seen my Edited Part, i made some clarification yesterday. Second thank you for helping. The charting software is Ninjatrader.com. It has 2 class OnBarUpdate and OnRender. https://ninjatrader.com/support/helpGuides/nt8/?onbarupdate.htm and https://ninjatrader.com/support/helpGuides/nt8/?onrender.htm , i am coding OnRender. That's why i am asking if there is a way to modify the public IList<double> CalculateResults(double startNumber, int barCount) part? I am an non-english speaking amateur programmer so i often use the wrong terms to express myself.

Comment: @Frankdot - so is it fair to assume that in my update you could replace 'WhateverTheChartingNameIs' to OnRender()?

Comment: I tried to copy/paste your solution between OnBarUpdate class and OnRender. Looks like it would take it but it sending back an error: NinjaScript File Error Code Line Column
NEWSDBA.cs Name 'RunCalculation' does not exist in current context CS0103 109 25 I had a conversation with their tech support about how to implement VS to NT: https://ninjatrader.com/support/forum/forum/ninjatrader-8/indicator-development/1123428-test-from-visual-studio-to-nt#post1123433

Comment: @Frankdot Yeah, you need to copy the private method above called 'RunCalculation'

Comment: However, worth noting, if you're not planning on using the 'results' list anywhere other than just printing the result from each calculation, you don't need that list.

Comment: ok in a small test with a new indicator it works by removing public void WhateverTheChartingNameIs(), now i have to modify the return part to get rid of the class RunCalculation and include that part in OnRender. Thank you